# Scrapy, scrape pages from second set of links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been going through the Scrapy documentation today and trying to get a working version of - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider - on a real world example. My example is slightly different in that it has 2 next pages, i.e.

> start_url > city page > unit page

It is the unit pages I want to grab data from.

My code:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.unitestudents.com/',
            ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.property-body'):
            yield {
                'name': quote.xpath('//span/a/text()').extract(),
                'type': quote.xpath('//div/h4/text()').extract(),
                'price_amens': quote.xpath('//div/p/text()').extract(),
                'distance_beds': quote.xpath('//li/p/text()').extract()
            }

            # Purpose is to crawl links of cities
            next_page = response.css('a.listing-item__link::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

            # Purpose is to crawl links of units
            next_unit_page = response.css(response.css('a.text-highlight__inner::attr(href)').extract_first())
            if next_unit_page is not None:
                                          next_unit_page = response.urljoin(next_unit_page)
                                          yield scrapy.Request(next_unit_page, callback=self.parse)
```

But when I run this I get:

```
INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

So I am thinking my code is not set up to retrieve the links in the flow mentioned above, but am not sure how best to do that?

Updated flow:

> Main page > City page > Building page > Unit page

It's still the unit page I want to get the data from.

Updated code:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.unitestudents.com/',
            ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.site-wrapper'):
            yield {
                'area_name': quote.xpath('//div/ul/li/a/span/text()').extract(),
                'type': quote.xpath('//div/div/div/h1/span/text()').extract(),
                'period': quote.xpath('/html/body/div/div/section/div/form/h4/span/text()').extract(),
                'duration_weekly': quote.xpath('//html/body/div/div/section/div/form/div/div/em/text()').extract(),
                'guide_total': quote.xpath('//html/body/div/div/section/div/form/div/div/p/text()').extract(),              
                'amenities': quote.xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li/p/text()').extract(),              
            }

            # Purpose is to crawl links of cities
            next_page = response.xpath('//html/body/div/footer/div/div/div/ul/li/a[@class="listing-item__link"]/@href').extract()
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

            # Purpose is to crawl links of units
            next_unit_page = response.xpath('//li/div/h3/span/a/@href').extract()
            if next_unit_page is not None:
                                          next_unit_page = response.urljoin(next_unit_page)
                                          yield scrapy.Request(next_unit_page, callback=self.parse)

            # Purpose to crawl crawl pages on full unit info

            last_unit_page = response.xpath('//div/div/div[@class="content__btn"]/a/@href').extract()
            if last_unit_page is not None:
                last_unit_page = response.urljoin(last_unit_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(last_unit_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Have you tested your XPaths with `scrapy shell http://www.unitestudents.com/` for example?

Comment: @paultrmbrth I had tested them, but noticed some flaws so I've made a few changes - see updated. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with the logic:

1. Scrape homepage - fetch all cities
2. Scrape city page - fetch all unit urls
3. Scrape unit page - get all desired data

I've made an example of how you could implement this in a scrapy spider below. I was not able to find all the info you mention in your example code, but I hope the code is clear enough for you to understand what it does and how to add the info you need.

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.unitestudents.com/',
            ]

    # Step 1
    def parse(self, response):
        for city in response.xpath('//select[@id="frm_homeSelect_city"]/option[not(contains(text(),"Select your city"))]/text()').extract(): # Select all cities listed in the select (exclude the "Select your city" option)
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin("/"+city), callback=self.parse_citypage)

    # Step 2
    def parse_citypage(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('//div[@class="property-header"]/h3/span/a/@href').extract(): #Select for each property the url
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_unitpage)

        # I could not find any pagination. Otherwise it would go here.

    # Step 3
    def parse_unitpage(self, response):
        unitTypes = response.xpath('//div[@class="room-type-block"]/h5/text()').extract() + response.xpath('//h4[@class="content__header"]/text()').extract()
        for unitType in unitTypes: # There can be multiple unit types so we yield an item for each unit type we can find.
            yield {
                'name': response.xpath('//h1/span/text()').extract_first(),
                'type': unitType,
                # 'price': response.xpath('XPATH GOES HERE'), # Could not find a price on the page
                # 'distance_beds': response.xpath('XPATH GOES HERE') # Could not find such info
            }
```

I think the code is pretty clean and simple. Comments should clarify why I chose to use the for loops. If something is not clear, let me know and I'll try to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for this, that helped! I was wondering where this comes from -
 `//div[@class="room-type-block"]/h5/text()`? I can't seem to find it on any of the pages.

Comment: As it turns out I just took one unit page, assuming it was the same for all other unit pages but it turns out it wasn't (and actually this page was more of an exception). I used [this webpage](http://www.unitestudents.com/bristol/waverley-house) but you are right; I cannot find this element on a lot of [other unit pages](http://www.unitestudents.com/glasgow/blackfriars). I've updated the code to handle both pages. (Note: I didn't test the full code)

Comment: Thank you for this, worked nicely! I was just wondering, why is it that this part - `callback=self.parse_citypage` - points to the next function? Sorry, this feel this is a RTFM question!

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're confused about but you tell Scrapy to fetch the specified url and tell it that when it acquired the data, it should call the specified callback function with the acquired response data. If the code answers your question, please check this answer as accepted.