# Scrapy: unclear if crawlspider is following pagination correctly

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

**Set-up**

I am scraping housing ads with scrapy following the example presented [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#more-examples-and-patterns).

In my case, I follow links to housing ad pages instead of author pages, and subsequently scrape the housing ad page for information.

My spider correctly scrapes information from the ads on a page and follows the pagination links to the next page.

---

**Problem**

There is only one start url used in the example, but I want to 'start' from a large number of urls, which are all located on one page. To obtain these urls I switched to a crawlspider.

The crawlspider obtains the urls, but is (seemingly) randomly mixing between following the pagination link and scraping housing ads.

---

**Code so far**

```
class RoomsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'rooms'
    allowed_domains = ['spareroom.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/london']

    # rules obtains the 'starting' urls
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(
        '//*[@id="spareroom"]/div[2]/aside[2]/ul/li/a',
        ),),callback='parse_page')]

    def parse_page(self, response):
        # follow links to ad pages
        for href in response.xpath(
               '//*[@id="maincontent"]/ul/li/article/header[1]',
               ).css('a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href),
                             callback=self.parse_ad)

        # follow pagination links
        next_page = response.xpath(
               '//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/ul[2]/li/strong/a/@href',
               ).extract_first()   
        if next_page is not None:
             next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
             yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_page)      

     def parse_ad(self, response):
     # code extracting ad information follows here, 
     # finalising the code with a yield function.
```

Ideally, per starting url the spider follows its ad links, scrapes its ads and follows its pagination links until there are no more pagination links.

Perhaps I should add a `Rule` to obtain the pagination links, and eliminate the `# follow pagination links` part? I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Why did you switch to CrawlSpider? If you remove `rules` and use `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider` I guess it should do what you want? Given that you provide proper extraction in `parse_ad`

Comment: Because I wanted to crawl a list of starting urls and crawlspider seems to be the spider to be fit for this? 

I should remove the `rules` but keep the `Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(
        '//*[@id="spareroom"]/div[2]/aside[2]/ul/li/a',
        ),),callback='parse_page')`? This results in an `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: To be honest I'm not the best person to advice you on how to do this with a `CrawlSpider` but you can use `Spider` to scrape a first page, collecting the urls (or starting urls as you seem to call them), and dive in. See my proposed answer in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493659/scrapy-scrape-pages-from-second-set-of-links/43497095#43497095) (which is an example of what I mean)

Comment: @Casper thanks for the link to your answer. I will use this if no-one can help me with Crawlspider.

Comment: @Casper. I've rewritten the code as in your answer. The result is seemingly the same as when I used the crawlspider set-up: it seems to be mixing following pagination links and scraping ads – it's not clear if all ads on a page are scraped. I'm not saying its not doing what its supposed to do, it's just impossible to follow what its doing.

Comment: you can compare the amount of items scraped with the amount listed on the webpage in order to check if all ads are scraped, can't you? I'm not 100% sure what you mean with "impossible to follow what it's doing". If it's about something you're not sure why you need a specific piece of code, you can ask. If you really want to follow it, you may add logging by adding `self.logger.debug('Log message goes here')` where `debug` could also be `info`, `warning`, or `error`.