# can we write another parse methon in same code for parsing data from newly generated url...?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

this is my parse method which gives me list of URLS, but in side the parse function i want to extract data from another url which i have generated which is named parse_url? 
    how to do that...?
i am very new to scrapy... please help me

```
def parse(self, response):
    base_url = "https://indiankanoon.org/"
    urlList=response.xpath('//div[@class="result_title"]/a/@href').extract()
    print("*********************Inside parse********************")
    time.sleep(5)
    for url in urlList:
    sepList = url.split('/')
    parse_url =base_url + 'doc' + '/' + sepList[2] + '/'
    fname=sepList[2]
    print('New Urls : {}\n The saved file name : {}.json'.format(parse_url, fname))

    for quote in response.css('div.judgments'):
        with open('datafile.json','w') as jfile:
            jfile.write(json.dumps({
                'Court': quote.css('div.docsource_main::text').extract(),
                'title': 'quote.xpath("//div[@class='judgments']/div[@class='doc_title']/text()").extract_first(),
                'subTitle': quote.css("div.judgments::text").extract_first(),
                'P_tags': quote.xpath("//div[@class='judgments']/p/text()").extract(),
                'Pre_tags': quote.xpath("//div[@class='judgments']/pre/text()").extract(),
                'blocked_quote': quote.xpath("//div[@class='judgments']/blockquote").extract()

                }))

enter code here
```

Comment: Can you give more of a clear indication of what you're trying to achieve and also other parts of your code that are important. For example you talk about a `parse_url` method which you also want help with. It would be useful to include that too.

Comment: def get_urls():
    URLS = []
#      URL = "https://indiankanoon.org/search/?formInput=doctypes%3A%20supremecourt%20fromdate%3A%20{start_date}%20todate%3A%20{end_date}&pagenum={num}"
    URL = "https://indiankanoon.org/search/?formInput=murder%20%20%20%20%20%20doctypes%3A%20judgments%20fromdate%3A%2{start_date}%20todate%3A%20{end_date}&pagenum={num}"
    for i in range(0, 2):
        for d in fetch_all():
            URLS.append(URL.format(start_date=get_first_day(d).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), end_date=get_last_day(d).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), num=i))
    return URLS

i am getting list of urls

Comment: Please edit your original post instead of providing extra detail on your question in comments.

Comment: But using parse function i am creating new url which is named as parse_url and i want to scrap data from that new url, but i am not able to get it.

Comment: thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scrapy.Request(parse_url, callback=self.parse_result)` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43497095/10351455). `parse_result` is called after getting the new response where you can continue scraping.

Comment: Yes It Worked. thanks a lot,, but i am getting 503 error code for mostly the sites.
can you suggest about that..?

Comment: If you can still access that page from another device, there is a chance that you're being blocked by the server. Try adding a `wait()` before each request is made.